# how to delete rows in just one section

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I created a table with 2 sections , I want the app when press the edit button to show the delete button in just the first section not the second section, I wrote the following code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
Book_own *temp= (Book_own *)[self.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source

    [books removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}

else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
}  
}
}
```

but when I press Edit button, it shows the delete button in both sections, How can I prevent this and make the delete in just first section???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        if(indexPath.section == yourVariable) return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

        else return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;

    }
```

Comment: Is this allows me to do (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) ?

Comment: yes you only play in UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone; this means in editing style only but what you mean UITableViewSelectionStyleNone we are not change any thing in it and that is responsible in firing didselectrowatindexpath

Answer (score 1):

'UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone ' can be set for a particular section in the delegate you already implemented.Just return it.

You can achieve it with following code:-

in cellForRowAtIndexPath :-

```
if(indexPath.section==0)
{
cell.editing=NO;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it still shows the delete button, but thanks for Your answer

Answer (score 1):

The `dataSource` can implement `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` to return YES or NO.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for that particular section:
 if(indexPath.section == editSection){

return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

}

```
    else{
```

return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;

}